# "Letter chooser" in own keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, key

H!

I am writing my own keyboard for android. It is something like standard T9 keyboard without dictionary. I have a problem to create special view when user trying choose correct letter.

I found application where is good way to solve it( below screen shot ), but I don't know how to do it.

Image: http://i.snag.gy/OL0Lk.jpg

My key:

```
<Key android:codes = "100,101,102" android:keyLabel = "def"  />
```

This "Letter chooser" floats on text( something like Toast ).

I tied write it as CandidatesView and keyPreviewLayout, but it is probably wrong idea:

- CandidatesView is not floating
- keyPreviewLayout --> I can't send all keyCodes to it

How to write it?

Thanks for any tips

Kamil4u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a PopupWindow, and place the view you want in it.  You'll have to set the WindowToken for the Popup by reading the one from you normal view and sticking it into the PopupWindow.